# Experience about OSGi memory consumption needed

Tags: memory-leaks, out-of-memory, osgi

We have an application that runs with OSGi with 1 GB RAM. It runs on some kind of embedded device and therefore is limited to 1 GB RAM. We use Felix without Karaf, because Karaf turned out to bog down the application too much.

The problem is now that we continously run into OutOfMemory errors. The heap dump analysis shows this picture:

- org.apache.felix: 30% (of which org.apache.felix.framework consumes 22 %)
- org.hsqldb: 22%
- io.vertx: 24%
- io.netty: 15%
- our own application package: 0.35%

My question is now whether OSGi aka Felix consuming 30% of the RAM at disposal for the application is "normal". Is there any experience how much RAM is >>typically<< consumed by OSGi? Do those 30% also include RAM used up by objects of our application or is this purely the RAM consumed by Felix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Establishing the memory owners is always tricky, and mostly non-intutive, and I find it often not that useful. I am not sure how you measure the memory layout but since Felix holds the roots, this might heavily skew the allotted amounts.

In my experience, when you get out of memory errors, there is some leak going on. So I tend to focus on what is the memory that grows after initial startup that is of the same type. Especially with lambdas today, it is very easy to create references that prohibit garbage collection.

If the Java VM has 1Gb then I fail to see how OSGi could be visible? The amount of memory needed by OSGi is quite minimal and should not grow after startup. Also, the fact that you had problems with Karaf seems to hint there is something fishy going on here. After initial startup, OSGi should be out of your way unless you use it in creative ways.

I assume you already set the different tuning parameters of the VM?

Ah well, I remember running OSGi in a 12Mb router ...

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Again some great answer that saved my day: "Ah well, I remember running OSGi in a 12Mb router ...". Sorry for the fuss. The developer that initially wrote the application is an OSGi guru. The two guys of us who are maintaining it know are not and we need to ask ...

Comment: Don't hesitate to contact me by email. You'd be surprised what a difference a few days consultancy can make :-)